# Render Page can't show the sql query return value (express.js with SQL Query)

Tags: javascript

`I use SQL to Query todo-list table and  get a return obj(Todo obj)

when i use the #each loop ,Render Page can get the value(Todo.Name)

but i cant show the value(Todo.Name) with not use #each in the Render Page
(because the return value just has only one record.so i dont use #each loop)

perhaps I am missing something.

```
    <p>{{Todo.Name}}</p><a href="/">One</a>
    <p>{{this.Name}}</p><a href="/">Two</a>

    {{#each Todo}}
      <li> {{this.Name}}
       <a href="./todos/{{this.ID}}">three</a></li>
    {{/each}}`
```

return obj(ToDo obj)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzgKc.png)

SELECT *   FROM [todo-list].[dbo].[todo]  Where ID='36'

[{ID:36 ,Name: 'Name-5'}]

Render Page result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJVll.png)

```
One         //cant show {{Todo.Name}}

Two         //cant show {{this.Name}}

Name-5 three //only this can show {{Todo.Name}}
```

How do I display data without using #each loop?`

Comment: Hi, please take a look here:  [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Use images with proper descriptions, and only if ithey are necessary